# Using shell to extract IDs from a server log?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have the following blob repeated many times within a file that has so sensible delimiter:

> "2020-05-12T07:51:56,071Z FATAL [] [message=Failed to process event xyz::5bf0726d-5927-32d0-92b3-5c741d9c15ec : association failed for the the id xyz::5bf0726d-5927-32d0-92b3-5c741d9c15ec , part (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: )] ... splunkcloud.com,

Something like.. `(xyz::[0-9A-Za-z-]+)`

I specifically would like to extract the ID `xyz::5bf0726d-5927-32d0-92b3-5c741d9c15ec` from this log (which is continuously  repeating. The value can end in an alphanumeric and it always starts with `xyz::`.

I ultimately want to cat the file in shell and run in through something like awk/sed so I can have just a line delimited file of these IDs. Thanks.

Comment: Can it be split across two lines?

Comment: Whatever works for me

Comment: How about `sed -n '/xyz::/{s/.*\(xyz::[^ ]*\).*/\1/;p;}'`?

Comment: I would suggest `sed '/xyz::/s/.*\(xyz::[^ ]*\) .*$/\1/'`  Which adds the space after the group match and the `$` anchor.  Also, no need for `-n` if you just end up printing anyway

Comment: Is there always a space after the ID ends? That could act as the delimiter.

Comment: @Ryan, this question needs more detail: what is the expected output? Give an example of it, do not explain it in words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -o 'xyz::[[:xdigit:]]\{8\}\(-[[:xdigit:]]\{4\}\)\{3\}-[[:xdigit:]]\{12\}' file
```

`[:xdigit:]` is a POSIX character class that matches `a-f`, `A-F`, or `0-9` characters. `\{8\}` matches eight occurrences. `\(-[[:xdigit:]]\{4\}\)\{3\}` matches three blocks of `-` hyphen followed with 4 xdigit characters. The match ends with `-` and 12 xdigit characters.